# how to skip read command in visual fox pro

Tags: visual-foxpro

i am calling an old vfp procedure through `DO WITH PARA COMMANDS`

when the command executes, it displays a form and Waits(Read command)

Can i skip this Read, through programing? so that it doesn't wait..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a VERY OLD program with an explicit `"READ"` command...  If you just comment out the read, will that work for you.  Are you trying to otherwise bypass some functionality based on parameters and just have the function continue?  If so, you could put an `IF` around the read for only the condition that you NEED it to stop.

Also, if the form is a `"MODAL" (WindowState = Modal)`, it will stay on that form until it is closed (or set to hidden) and returns back to calling source to continue execution.

Showing some context of the form, procedure might help other options.

Comment: yes.. am working on some integration project with an old legacy system. 
the if condition is a good idea.. Thanks..